# VBA - Take values from selected Range (F$1:F$100) in Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I try to create an array with values from a range of selected cells.

What I have so far is following:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$3:$F$100").Select
varGetArrayAll = Selection
```

But it only creates the array with the first cell F3.

I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: varGetArrayAll = ActiveSheet.Range("$F$3:$F$100").Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the Range into a 1-D array, then use `Application.Transpose`, like in the line below:

```
varGetArrayAll = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("$F$3:$F$100").Value)
```

However, you shouldn't rely on `ActiveSheet`, you should fully qualify your `Range` with the worksheet is it in, like in the code below:

```
' replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name
varGetArrayAll = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$F$3:$F$100").Value)
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you. Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim vargetArrayAll  As Range 'or as Variant, to look like your code.
    Dim counter         As Long

    Set vargetArrayAll = Selection

    For counter = 1 To vargetArrayAll.Count
        Debug.Print vargetArrayAll(counter)
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Thus, you set the value as a range and you can acces its elements as if it is an array. However, you start with `1`, not with `0`.